# Dice probability being modified

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, number-theory

So for a roll20 D&D game I been working on I decided it'd be nice to have a macro that would calculate the probability of successfully hitting an enemy and showing it as a percentage.

To hit an enemy you must roll higher on your accuracy than their evasion, and both of these rolls are D20s. However, both accuracy and evasion are increased/decreased by various attributes and proficiencies.

From what I remember probability is the winning possibilities / total possibilities.

What I'm having problems with though is figuring out what the winning possibilities are when the accuracy/evasion bonuses/debuffs are applied.

I know that using triangular numbers you could calculate the chances of rolling a number equal to or higher than a 2nd dice roll. However, I do not know what math formula to use to calculate the modifiers.

For example: This is the possibilities for 2d6 with no modifiers
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 &1&2&3&4&5&6 \\ \hline \\
1&=&<&<&<&<&< \\
2&>&=&<&<&<&< \\
3&>&>&=&<&<&< \\
4&>&>&>&=&<&< \\
5&>&>&>&>&=&< \\
6&>&>&>&>&>&= \\
\end{array}
However, if you had a +1 added to your rolls then the possibilities for 2d6 would look like this:
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 &1&2&3&4&5&6 \\ \hline \\
1&<&<&<&<&<&< \\
2&=&<&<&<&<&< \\
3&>&=&<&<&<&< \\
4&>&>&=&<&<&< \\
5&>&>&>&=&<&< \\
6&>&>&>&>&=&< \\
\end{array}

So my problem is I can't figure out the formula used to calculate the increase each time. No mod 2d6 is 21 wins, but +1 would by 26 (+5), +2 would be 30 (+9) and +3 would be 33 (+12)

I apologise if this has been asked before in some way and I haven't found it. My internet has been pretty bad today so the amount of searching I done was limited.

Comment: It appears that you are looking at two dice rolls. You are looking for the number of ways that one die roll can beat another die roll when one of the dice is modified. Is that correct?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe For the D&D style combat system that i've been making the attacker would roll accuracy and then the defender would roll evasion. Depending on a character's stats they may get bonuses to their accuracy or evasion. So Both dice could be modified or have no modifiers at all. My goal is to make a macro that would calculate what the probability is of you (the attacker) rolling higher than or equal to the defender with whatever bonuses both players may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no bonus, the probability of a successful hit (assuming ties go in favor of the attacker) would be $\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{20})=\frac{21}{40}$, seen easily by noting the probability that the two roll exactly the same is $\frac{1}{20}$ and the remaining cases split evenly between favoring the attacker and favoring the defender.

For a net difference of $1$ in favor of the attacker (*E.g. by having +1 to attack rolls and +0 to defense, or +5 to attack and +4 to defense, etc...*) we would include an additional $19$ favorable scenarios for the attacker out of the $400$ possible outcomes of rolling two dice giving a probability of $\frac{229}{400}$

A net difference of $2$ in favor of the attacker would give an additional $18$ more favorable scenarios beyond those mentioned in the previous paragraph giving a probability of $\frac{247}{400}$, so on and so forth.

In general: for a net difference of $n\geq 0$ in favor of the attacker, the probability would be $\dfrac{-n^2+39n+420}{800}$

This was found by recurrence relations, letting $f(0)=\frac{21}{40}$ and $f(n)=f(n-1)+\frac{20-n}{400}$ by generalizing the observations made above.

A similar technique can be applied in the reverse direction to get the probabilities for if the defender has the advantage, or you can just use the values already found for the attacker having the advantage and subtracting away from $1$.  The probability of a successful attack with a net difference of $n\geq 1$ in favor of the defender would correspond to $1$ minus the corresponding probability of a successful attack with net difference of $n-1$ in favor of the attacker.

Comment: In D&D, I believe if $n=0$ the rule is that on a tie, you have a roll-off. Each player (attacker and defender) both roll until there is a clear winner. So, I think for $n=0$, the probability is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. This would give the formula:

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{2}, & n=0 \\ \dfrac{-n^2+39n+420}{800}, & n>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @interstellarprobe in dnd the defender doesn't roll at all.  They simply have a defense score which the attacker tries to roll higher than. If you were to assume a reroll on a tie, then the formula needs quite a bit of reworking and what you write in the comments would not be correct as that still has ties in favor of attacker for n>0

Comment: If advantage should go in favor of defender for ties, just replace every occurrence of the word "attacker" and it's variants with "defender" and vice versa

Comment: So N is the result of (attack mod - defence mod)
meaning if you have 1 extra attack than their defence it'd be (1^2+(39*1)+420) / 800 ?
Still confused about the 39, 420 and 800.

Comment: Yes (though you seem to have missed the negative sign on the first term).  The numbers you point at happen to appear in the closed form of the solution and so are relevant in that sense, but they are not easy to spot without calculations. I can assure you though that they didn't get pulled out of thin air.

Comment: @JMoravitz in D&D, there are plenty of opposed rolls. One example is Stealth vs Perception. Both the character making the stealth check and the one making the perception check each roll their respective skill check (sometimes with additional circumstance modifiers) and they compare the results. If the result is a tie, you compare modifiers (whomever has the larger modifier wins the opposed check). If the modifiers are equal, then you have a roll-off. For your function, this occurs when $n=0$ only. For $n>0$, the attacker has the higher modifier, so ties would go to the attacker.